# Averaging oscillatory data

Tags: numerics, curve-fitting, oscillations, smoothing

I have an oscillatory data generated vs time as shown below. Essentially, I want this data to be averaged and free of any oscillations. I am not satisfied with the results from a simple moving average algorithm. Which moving algorithms or approaches are worth trying?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use digital filters, e.g a high order (e.g. 10) low pass Butterworth filter, with the cutoff frequency such that the high frequencies are removed. You should perform a Forward-Backward filtering so that no phase discrepancy is introduced (filter once in the direction of increasing time, then once more in reverse). This is done in MATLAB via `filtfilt` and in Python via `scipy.signal.filtfilt` for instance. You may need to ensure that your signal is sampled on a uniform time grid. This can be done via interpolation.
High-order filters are required if some frequencies which you want to keep are very close to some that you wish to keep. The downside is that higher-order filters have a longer step response, i.e. they may react slowly to steps in the signal and may produce some ringing.

Note that this procedure may behave slightly badly near the boundaries, but that is usually not very problematic in my experience. Using a High-Order filter is useful when there are frequencies that need to be kept but which are close to slightly higher frequencies which you want to discard. If the high frequencies to remove are much larger than the ones you are interested in, lower-order filters will also work nicely.

EDIT: Here is a short Python example with a signal (cosh) perturbed by 2 sinusoids of different frequencies :

```py
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate perturbed signal
t = np.linspace(0,1,1000)
f1 = 500.
f2 = 20.
y = np.cosh(3*t) + np.cos(2*np.pi*f1*t) + np.cos(2*np.pi*f2*t)

# 1 - Filter high frequencies
fs=1/(t[1]-t[0])
order = 5

fcut = 100.
sos = signal.butter(N=order, Wn=[fcut], btype='lowpass', output='sos', fs=fs)
yfilt = signal.sosfiltfilt(sos, y, padlen=int(y.size*4/5))

# 2 - Also try to filter lower frequencies
fcut = 10.
sos = signal.butter(N=order, Wn=[fcut], btype='lowpass', output='sos', fs=fs)
yfilt2 = signal.sosfiltfilt(sos, y, padlen=int(y.size*4/5))

# Plot signals
plt.figure(dpi=300)
plt.plot(t,y, label='original', alpha=0.6)
plt.plot(t,yfilt, label='filtered')
plt.plot(t,yfilt2, label='filtered2')
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Effect of filtering')
```

EDIT2: If the behavior at the boundary is problematic, you can fix it manually, for instance by making a weighted average with a better behaved solution, with weights depending on the "distance" to the boundaries.
[image: result]

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. unfortunately, i need it's behavior to be good at the boundaries as well. are there any alternative methods?

Comment: @SthavishthaBhopalam I have updated my answer with an example, so that you can judge if my solution is acceptable for you.